# Passing parameters to my custom logger in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, logging

I am having some troubles using the logger service in Symfony2. I find it quite confusing.

I am trying to use a [Rotating File Handler](https://github.com/ideatosrl/corso-Symfony2/blob/master/vendor/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/RotatingFileHandler.php). To this handler zou can pass 3 paramenters: the filename of the log, maxFiles that the log can divide itself and log level.

I want to pass this parameters from the controller, since I load that data in runtime from a `.ini` configuration file, but I am not sure how to do it.

How could I do this?

Comment: Question is unclear, please add more info - it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im trying to use the `rotating file handler`, but I dont know how to.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you create a service and pass the pass as service argument. Then, that service has it's name which you should be able to use in logger config section.

Comment: oh sorry... I meant "... and pass it as service argument."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following in your controller:

1. add a use statement: `use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;`
2. use it like this: `$handler = new RotatingFileHandler(__DIR__.'/Fixtures/foo.rot', 2);`

Comment: and how do I apply the handler to the logger service?

Comment: $log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler($handler);